# Make PDO connection variable accessible throughout site

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I am beginning to convert all old mysql_ functions to PDO and have a little trouble grasping this concept. I want to be able to access my PDO connection variable throughout my function pages so that it can be called as needed without making a connection script at the beginning of each function. I'll try to explain my setup as best as possible.

This is my init.php page that loads all required php pages. This page is included at the top of each of my pages, but not function pages.

**init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(E_All);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/trainer.php';
?>
```

Here is my connect file that opens my db connection. Yes I have a `mysql_connect` open as well because I can not disable all my other functions while converting all the others over to PDO.

**connect.php**

```
<?php 

$connect_error = 'Sorry there is a problem with the database connection.';
mysql_connect('Localhost', 'customn7', 'I<3deadlifts!') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('customn7_cm') or die($connect_error) or die($connect_error);
?>

<?php   

//PDO database connect
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'Localhost',
    'username'  => 'customn7',
    'password'  => '********',
    'dbname'    => 'customn7_cm'
);

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$config['db']['host']. ';dbname=' .$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} 

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Here is my `functions/trainer.php` where the function is written:

**trainer.php**

```
function exist_client_to_class($cd){
list($user_id, $class_id, $first_name, $last_name, $nickname) = explode('|', $cd);

try{

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO clients 
(`user_id`, class_id, first_name, last_name, nickname, date)
VALUES (:user_id, :class_id, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname, CURDATE())
');

$stmt->execute(array(
        ':user_id' => $user_id, 
        ':class_id' => $class_id, 
        ':first_name' => $first_name,
        ':last_name' => $last_name,
        ':nickname' => $nickname)
        );
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

}
```

As of now I can not access my `$db` variable from my trainers.php page. Can someone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that calls the function:

```
// Post Selected name to current class.
if (isset($_POST['exist_to_class'])){
if (empty($_POST['client_data']) === true){
    $errors [] = 'You much select a client to be added to the class.';
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['client_data']) && !empty($_POST['client_data']));
    foreach ($_POST['client_data'] as $cd){
     exist_client_to_class($db, $cd);
     header('Location: view_class.php?class_id='.$class_id.' ');
    } // foreach $cd
} // else

} //isset
```

Comment: Create a trainers class and inject the `$db` object into its constructor

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215466/changed-connection-page-to-pdo-and-got-mysql-error/13215671#13215671

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I strongly recommend you don't listen to anyone telling you to set it as global.

---

Pass the connection object to the function, using an argument:

```
exist_client_to_class(PDO $pdo, $cd) { //...
```

That's a simplified version of what's called Dependency Injection.

A more robust version includes by wrapping your functions into classes (and instantiating objects from those classes), and passing the PDO object (or some sort of Factory object) to the constructor of that object. Then it would be "globally" available throughout the methods (functions) of that object.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. In the case of my current function it would look like `exist_client_to_class(PDO $db, $cd){`? Thats it?

Comment: Yes, when you call it, you pass the PDO object as the first argument, and it would be accessible in the function using the `$db` variable.

Comment: so inside my function I should be able to do a `var_dump ($db)` and get something returned?

Comment: Yes, you'll get the PDO connection object details

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of....not working. No errors but I dont get anything output to the browser either.

Comment: @Colbyd: Could you paste your code and show us? How you're calling the function and how you've defined it.

Comment: I posted code above, but I figured it out. I was not passing it when I called the function. Is there any advantage/disadvantage to doing it this way as opposed to wrapping in a class like @Lawrence Cherone suggested above?

Comment: @Colbyd: Wrapping all of your logic into classes and objects is a more robust solution, and is generally better. However, for existing projects, you may want to not change your code structure so drastically. Learn OOP and proper encapsulation, then go with Lawrence's solution.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Makes perfect sense and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Dont use global if you can help it.

As your kinda bootstrapping with your init.php file you can dependency inject the connection.

Altered **connect.php**

```
<?php 
//PDO database connect
$config['db'] = array(
'host'      => 'Localhost',
'username'  => 'customn7',
'password'  => '********',
'dbname'    => 'customn7_cm'
);

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$config['db']['host']. ';dbname=' .$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Sorry there is a problem with the database connection :' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**trainer.php**

```
class trainer_model{
    function __construct(PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function exist_client_to_class($cd){
        list($user_id, $class_id, $first_name, $last_name, $nickname) = explode('|', $cd);

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO clients
        (`user_id`, class_id, first_name, last_name, nickname, date)
        VALUES (:user_id, :class_id, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname, CURDATE())');

            $stmt->execute(array(
            ':user_id' => $user_id,
            ':class_id' => $class_id,
            ':first_name' => $first_name,
            ':last_name' => $last_name,
            ':nickname' => $nickname)
            );
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}


$trainer = new trainer_model($db);
//Then use as an object method
$trainer->exist_client_to_class($cd);
```

Comment: Would I wrap each function in a `class`? I dont understand what you mean by `//Then use as an object method`. Sorry but I am very new to OOP and having to kind of relearn how I was taught PHP.

Comment: I did not accept this answer as I am so new to `OOP` that this would drastically change all my code and Im just not there with with my understanding of classes and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use an inifile and a function with a static variable in it?
Like this:

```
function pdo_connect() {
  static $pdo;
  $dsn="";
  $opt="";`enter code here`
  $charset = 'utf8';

  if(!isset($pdo)) {
    $config = parse_ini_file(_INIFILE_);
  }

  $dsn = "mysql:host=".$config['db_server'].";dbname=".$config['db_name'].";charset=".$charset;
  $opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
  ];

  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $opt);   

  if($pdo === false) { 
    return "PDO connection ERROR:".PHP_EOL.";
  }

  return $pdo;

}//pdo
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to make a global file php which you can require/include to all the files that needs database connection....

then use global $db inside your function

function exist_client_to_class($cd){

global $db;

}

Answer (score -3):

Your `trainers.php` script actually does have access to `$db`.  For example, if you added `var_dump($db)` as the first line of `trainers.php`, you would see you have access to it.

The problem you are having is that the functions within `trainers.php` do not have access to `$db` within the SCOPE of the function.  There are really a few ways to handle this.

The simplest (and most hackish IMO), is to add the line

```
global $db;
```

As the first line WITHIN each function you want to provide access to the `$db` variable that is in global scope.

Another way would be to simply pass the DB object as a parameter to every function that needs access to it like this (dependency injection):

```
function exist_client_to_class($cd, $db){
    // your function logic
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
exist_client_to_class($cd, $db);
```

A final (and in my opinion best) way to do this if you build a singleton class around your PDO object and get the PDO object from that, guraneeting only a single instance will ever be created.  That might look like this

```
class db {

    protected static $pdo_instance = NULL;

    protected static $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=somedb;host=127.0.0.1'; // your DSN

    protected static $user = 'username';

    protected static $password = 'password';

    protected function __construct() {
        try {
            self::$pdo_instance = new PDO (self::$dsn, self::$user, self::$password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return 'PDO Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static function get_pdo_instance() {
        if (isset(self::$pdo_instance) && self::$pdo_instance instanceof PDO) {
           return self::$pdo_instance;
        } else {
           $result = self::__construct();
           if (true === $result) {
                return self::$pdo_instance;
           } else {
               throw new Exception($result); // or however you want to handle the connection error
           }        
    }
}
```

To access, instead of using `$db` everywhere, just do

```
$db = db::get_pdo_instance();
```

within your functions.

Or you can even call directly lile

```
$stmt = db::get_PDO_instance()->prepare('YOUR SQL HERE');
```

You might even consider a mix of singleton and dependency injection like this:

```
function exist_client_to_class($cd, $db){
    // your function logic
}

exist_client_to_class($cd, db::get_PDO_instance());
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @MikeBrant , there is no difference between using global variable and singleton. NONE. In addition to that, you code also violates OCP.

Comment: @tereško The difference between using a global variable and a singleton is the difference between functional programming and object oriented programming. The singleton can include logic to set itself up.

Comment: @JonHulka That makes no sense. Using a singleton is unrelated to functional programming and is a very, very poor OOP practice.

Comment: @Lusitanian I think I might need to read up on this one. There seems to be an overwhelming opinion in your favour with regard to PHP.

Comment: @tereško I don't understand your issue in this case with singleton. For this developer's case, dependency injection is going to still pass in a globally defined PDO object, and his functions are going to be tightly coupled to PDO in that he doesn't seem to be writing an entire database abstraction layer, so I don't think that the problems that people typically associate with singleton (i.e. hard to unit test) is really an issue here.  I also don't see him polluting global scope with multiple pointers to the instance, in that he would be opening pointers in limited function scope.

Comment: I actually just edited answer, as really I would think including the dependency injection aspect in the function definitions could be used in conjunction with a singleton for the PDO object.

Answer (score -4):

Create a singleton Database class:

```
class Database
{
    protected static $instance=false;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$instance===false) self::$instance=new Database();
        return $instance;
    }
    protected function __construct()
    {
        //Connect here
    }
    //Whatever other functions you need
}
```

to use it:

```
$db=Database::getInstance();
$connection=$db->getConnection();...
```

Comment: If you go that way, you might as well use `global`; less code and the same effect...

Comment: @jeroen This encapsulates in more nicely. My Database has some convenience functions as well and handles closing cursors.

Comment: It doesn't encapsulate anything. You are using a global state.

Comment: @tereško Creation of the connection is handled once, the first time it is needed, or not at all. There is no need to put the startup code at the top of every script, and no wasted resources if the database isn't needed.

Comment: I believe singleton is a good idea if you want to maintain that single object through your entire code execution.  The code sample here really is not that applicable to PDO object instantiation though.  Also it won;t work in that your a trying to actually instantiate an object by calling `new Database()` that will fail as the contructor is protected.  You would need to do `self::__construct()` there.

Comment: @MikeBrant the constructor is visible from within it's own class. `new Database()` works. I suppose this example is better suited to the context in which I am actually using it; where all database access happens through calls to the Database member functions.

Comment: @JonHulka , please go and learn what global state is , before you continue giving people "advice".

Comment: One thing is for certain - I won't be recommending singleton classes for PHP questions on SO again!

Comment: Singletons create global state. Which part you cannot understand ?

Comment: @tereško Global state was your term, not mine. I just don't see how to cleanly get away from it here. Either you use a singleton, or you use a global variable. How about some constructive input on how to solve this problem?